Regarding the communication strategy and working principle between k8s service nodeport and iptables
Environment:
Kubernetes master: 192.168.174.110
Kubernetes work-node-01: 192.168.174.125
Kubernetes work-node-02: 192.168.174.126
Kubernetes version: v1.31.2-1.1
Installation method: kubeadm init
Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
CNI and version: calico v3.29.0
CRI and version: containerd://2.0.0
All kube-proxy nodes use the iptables proxy mode.
root@k8s-master-01:/download# kubectl logs kube-proxy-8bsgh -n kube-system
I1 126 06:45:53.566881 1 server_linux.go:66] "Using iptables proxy"
I was able to successfully communicate via a web browser on a laptop by accessing http://192.168.174.110:32670.
Additionally, I checked the iptables rules and did not find any related DNAT rules for port 32670. I also used the command "netstat -nat|grep 32670" on the Kubernetes master host to check for any listening ports related to 32670, but none were found.
So I don't understand how the 32670 port here directs traffic requests to the final pod node? Please help me explain it, thank you.
[kubectl get deployments,pods,service,endpoints -n test-k8s -o wide]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/6uJJRRBM.png
